# xargs with git checkout fails with pathspec error

Tags: bash, xargs

When I run the below command

`git branch | grep solution- | cut -c 3- | xargs git checkout`

I get this error output

```
error: pathspec 'solution-2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'solution-3' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

When I run the below command

`git checkout solution-1 && git checkout solution-2 && git checkout solution-3`

I get this correct output

```
Switched to branch 'solution-1'
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Switched to branch 'solution-2'
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Switched to branch 'solution-3'
Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I don't understand why git is failing on the xargs version.

Finally, just to prove that xargs is getting the correct arguments if I run `git branch | grep solution- | cut -c 3- | xargs echo` I get `solution-1 solution-2 solution-3` which is what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I conclude that you have a git repo with 3 branches solution-1, solution-2 & solution-3.

Now when you run the below command

```
git checkout solution-1 && git checkout solution-2 && git checkout solution-3
```

you get correct output because the git checkout gets a valid branch name each time (it ran 3 time with different branch name).

Now, lets see why you get error when running below command,

```
git branch | grep solution- | cut -c 3- | xargs git checkout
```

Running the above command is **equivalent to running** ,

```
git checkout solution-1 solution-2 solution-3
```

which will prompt you the **same error**. This is because git checkout only executed one time with **solution-1 as branch** name and solution-2 & solution-3 as file names.

Now, you actually want to switch branches one by one for each argument from xargs. To do this you can run the below command.

```
git branch | grep solution- | cut -c 3- | xargs -d '\n' -n1  git checkout
```

Comment: OSX xargs doesn't show a "-d" argument. If you could explain what that argument is suppose to be maybe it will help find a solution for OSX